# jquery/javascript : How to create multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to create an multidimensional array like from :

```
output['deptorAccount'][0] = 'value1'
output['deptorAccount'][1] = 'value2'
output['deptorAccount'][2] = 'value3'
output['deptorAccount'][3] = 'value4'

output['paymentDate'][0] = 'value1'
output['paymentDate'][1] = 'value2'
output['paymentDate'][2] = 'value3'
output['paymentDate'][3] = 'value4'
```

How do i do it?

Comment: on which item you have to do a each loop ?

Comment: That isn't a multi dimensional array. You have a single array called `deptorAccount` on the `output` object which you are then adding elements to.

Comment: There are a million and a half ways to accomplish this. In order to better provide assistance we need more information. What have you tried so far? Have you gotten any errors?

Comment: What you have there is a single level array called `output.deptorAccount = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4']`

Comment: @phuzi i update my question!

Comment: @MichaelSorensen I have a loop that these commands are located inside but it does not work properly! What do you do if you want to write it with the **for** command?

Comment: This is still not a multidimensional array! You have an object with two separate arrays called `deptorAccount` and `paymentDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected output actually shows an **object** with the keys **paymentDate** and **deptorAccount**. This two keys hold a simple array - so this ain't a two-dimensional array.

Nevertheless this can be done programatically using a for-loop, populating both arrays with values:

```js
output = {
  deptorAccount: [],
  paymentDate: []
};

for (var a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
  output['deptorAccount'].push("value" + (a + 1));
  output['paymentDate'].push("value" + (a + 1));
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like :

```js
function assignData(output, propName, values){
  output[propName] = [];

 $.each(values, function( index, value ) {  
  output[propName][index] = value;
});
  return output;
}

var output = {};
output = assignData(output,'deptorAccount',['value1','value2','value3','value4']);
output = assignData(output,'paymentDate',['value1','value2','value3','value4']);
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays don't have named elements, named elements are in objects. So you need an object whose properties are each arrays.

You can create it with an object literal containing array literals.

```
const output = {
    debtorAccount: ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"],
    paymentDate: ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
};
```